# How can I turn a string into a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

How can I turn a string (like `'hello'`) into a list (like `[h,e,l,l,o]`)?

Comment: Note that the list will be of strings, `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`.

Comment: Strings in Python behave like lists of characters.  E.g. `'hello'[1]` -> `'e'`.  Are you sure you need a list?

Comment: @PeterGraham: Good point, I've added some description of that to my answer.

Answer (score 47):

The `list()` function <sup>[[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list)]</sup> will convert a string into a list of single-character strings.

```
>>> list('hello')
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Even without converting them to lists, strings already behave like lists in several ways. For example, you can access individual characters (as single-character strings) using brackets:

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> s[1]
'e'
>>> s[4]
'o'
```

You can also loop over the characters in the string as you can loop over the elements of a list:

```
>>> for c in 'hello':
...     print c + c,
... 
hh ee ll ll oo
```