# PYthon - List of strings into a nested list of strings, where each list contains the elements of each each strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Basically, I have this:

```
ls = [
    '###',
    '# a',
    '#b#'
]
```

and want it to be like:

```
ls = [
    ['#', '#', '#'], 
    ['#', ' ', 'a'],
    ['#', 'b', '#']
]
```

Anyone could help me out?

Comment: What have you tried already? (Hint, this is string handling 101.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I turn a string into a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522533/how-can-i-turn-a-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert each string to a list in a list comprehension

```
>>> [list(s) for s in ls]
[['#', '#', '#'], ['#', ' ', 'a'], ['#', 'b', '#']]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a list comprehension you can loop through your list and apply some operation on your list items. By putting these items into the `list` operator you turn an iterable into a list. Because a string is basically a iterable of characters you can convert it into a list of characters with `list`.

```
ls = [
    '###',
    '# a',
    '#b#'
]

[list(x) for x in ls]
>> [['#', '#', '#'], ['#', ' ', 'a'], ['#', 'b', '#']]
```

Comment: Your answer could be more useful if you also explained what your code does instead of just listing the code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(map(list, ls)))  # [['#', '#', '#'], ['#', ' ', 'a'], ['#', 'b', '#']]
```